# How to strip UTM tags in Varnish without stripping queries I want?

Tags: caching, varnish, dynamic-queries

I'm looking for some help with a rule (a regex) in Varnish that I'm using to ensure that, e.g., UTM tags don't create a new cached entry for every unique query I receive. Here's my rule:

```
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|\&)(utm|gclid|fbclid|mc)(_|=)") {
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?.*", "");
}
```

This works fine. The problem comes if there is another query in the string that I do *not* want to get rid of. For example: if the request is to `https://example/page/?fbclid=45435`, then the rule works fine. Irrespective of what's in the `fbclid` part, the same page is loaded from the backend. But if the `fbclid` part comes after *another* query—if, e.g., the request is to `https://example/page/?app=346&fbclid=45435`—then, obviously, it breaks the first part of the string as well, and returns the /page/ without the important query ever being processed. (Naturally, I have told Varnish not to cache requests that go to `?app=`).

I am not especially good in this area, so I want to make sure that I'm thinking about this the right way. If I were to change my rule so that it didn't look for the `&`, then the example I gave above would be fixed. But it would also mean that the UTM tags stuck around after the query I wanted to keep, and were passed to the back end to be cached.

Basic question: what's the best way for me to strip out the `utm`, `gclid`, `fbclid`, and `mc` tags *irrespective* of where they show up in the string, without getting rid of whatever other queries are in there too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to [Varnish - use the cache when UTM_, gclid and other campaign params are used, otherwise pass if other querystring present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75672194/varnish-use-the-cache-when-utm-gclid-and-other-campaign-params-are-used-oth/75693655)

Here's how I would typically strip campaign parameters from the URL:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(fbclid |utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|mc|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "&(fbclid |utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|mc|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=([A-z0-9_\-\.%25]+)", "");
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "\?(fbclid |utm_source|utm_medium|utm_campaign|utm_content|gclid|mc|cx|ie|cof|siteurl)=([A-z0-9_\-\.%25]+)", "?");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?&", "?");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?$", "");
    }
}
```

Please set this code to see if it works. Maybe also read the question I referenced at the top.

Comment: Thank you! I shall try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [vmod_querysting](https://github.com/Dridi/libvmod-querystring), which is safer and easier to use than `regsub()` / `regsuball()`. There is also an example specifically mentioning UTM in the documentation.